# VC++ Standard Lib - possible compiler datatype declaration error for int_fast16_t and uint_fast16_t

Tags: c++, visual-c++, std

While building the table below and hovering over over the unremarked std::int_fast16_t and std::uint_fast16_t i found that they are declared as int and unsigend int, rather then short and unsigned short. For all other datatypes in the table the declarations are as expected.

I use the latest version of Visual Studio. It could be either a VC C++ Standard library implementation error or an Intellisense problem. Can anyone confirm.

To reproduce just type : std::int_fast16 or std::uint_fast16 and hover over it with the mouse pointer.

```
//std::int8_t                           :  8 bits       : signed char, char
//      std:int_fast8_t
//      std::int_least8_t
//std::uint8_t                          :  8 bits       : unsigend char
//      std::uint_fast8_t
//      std::uint_least8_t
//std::int16_t                          : 16 bits       : signed short, short
//      std::int_fast16_t                               : <<<< int 32 bit !!! <<<<<<<
//      std::int_least16_t
//std::uint16_t                         : 16 bits       : unsigned short
//      std::uint_fast16_t                              : <<<< unsigned int 32 bit !!! 
//      std::uint_least16_t
//std::int32_t                          : 32 bits       : signed int, int
//      std::int_fast32_t
//      std::int_least32_t
//std::uint32_t                         : 32 bits       : unsigned int
//      std::uint_fast32_t
//      std::uint_least32_t
//std::int64_t                          : 64 bits       : signed long long, long long
//      std::int_fast64_t
//      std::int_least64_t
//std::uint64_t                         : 64 bits       : unsigned long long
//      std::uint_fast64_t
//      std::uint_least64_t
```

Comment: 16-bit integral types are not fast on 32-bit and 64-bit processors.

Comment: What is your reason for tagging C? How does that second language come in?

Comment: In 32- and 64-bit x86 code, a 16-bit operand needs a size-override prefix. That makes the machine code longer. So using an `int`instead of a `short` results in smaller code, that might execute faster. That is their interpretation of `fast16` (the standard doesn't specify what should be "fast" with these types).

Comment: @Yunnosh, The primitives of C++ are declared with primitives of C.

Comment: @Hans, are you saying that the declaration is correct? Because if you store this variable it  uses double the byte size the expected with 16bit variables.

Comment: @Bob, that I understand, but as I replied to Hans, the '16' implies 16 bit storage, yet this has 32 bit storage.

Comment: Yes, the declaration is correct.  Thinking of variables is not that productive, the processor executes the vast amount of integral operation with CPU registers.  Very important to speed.  Registers which are 32-bit or 64-bit today.

Comment: @Morph As you already stated, C++ takes its standard integer types directly from C, [which states](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.20p2): "fastest integer types **having at least certain specified widths**".

Comment: `uint_fast16_t` - _"fastest unsigned integer type with width of __at least__ 16 bits"_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: @Morph - No, all the `16`-types should be able to hold a 16-bit value. The `least16` would accept 18 bits, if that is what's available. The `fast16` puts more emphasis on "fast", so might be even bigger (or not ,on a 16-bit processor).

Comment: @BoP the std::int_fast8_t  and std::uint_fast8_t are declared as signed and unsigned char,  just asking, is that emphasis on 'fast' too?

Comment: @Morph - Yes, 8-bit instructions are special. The original 8086 had instructions for 8-bit and 16-bit values. When "growing" to 32 bits, the processors reused the 16-bit codes to have new meaning. If you want 16-bit operands, you have to add an "old meaning" prefix to each instruction. That made 32-bit code faster in 32-bit mode, and 16-bit code slower (but it still ran faster than the 8086, because the MHz were much higher).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's intended. `(u)intXX_fast_t` is supposed to be any signed/unsigned integer type that has *at least* `XX` bit width and is the most performant such type for the underlying architecture. There is no guarantee that they are *exactly* 16bit wide. That would be `(u)intXX_t`.

`short` is very like 16bit wide and 16bit wide types are less performant on x86/x86-64 CPUs and probably most other 32bit or 64bit architectures as well.

(Of course performance is relative and it is up to the C++ implementation to decide what exactly it means. For example if the program is limited by RAM throughput, then a smaller type will benefit it regardless of whether individual operations on the type are easier for the CPU to do.)